# How to get specific value after parsing an XML?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-parsing

i am creating an app with Xamarin android, Here i am parsing an XML response which i got from a web request.
here is the xml response -

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <IsActive xmlns="http://CTRMService/CTRM">true</IsActive>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <GetAllPersonResponse xmlns="http://CTRMService/CTRM">
         <GetAllPersonResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DTOModelLayer.DTO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:DTOCtrmSetupPerson>
               <a:CTRM_SETUP_PERSON_COMPANY_LINK i:nil="true"/>
               <a:Company_Id i:nil="true"/>
               <a:Customer_Id>1</a:Customer_Id>
               <a:Email_Address i:nil="true"/>
               <a:First_Name>Admin</a:First_Name>
               <a:Invoice_Contact_Enum>false</a:Invoice_Contact_Enum>
               <a:Job_Title_Enum i:nil="true"/>
               <a:Last_Modify_Date>2017-04-24T17:12:22.657</a:Last_Modify_Date>
               <a:Last_Name>Admin</a:Last_Name>
               <a:Lock_Id>0</a:Lock_Id>
               <a:Middle_Name i:nil="true"/>
               <a:Modify_Person_Id>1</a:Modify_Person_Id>
               <a:Person_Id>1</a:Person_Id>
               <a:Person_Initials i:nil="true"/>
               <a:Status_Enum>true</a:Status_Enum>
               <a:System_Default_Enum>true</a:System_Default_Enum>
            </a:DTOCtrmSetupPerson>
            <a:DTOCtrmSetupPerson>
               <a:CTRM_SETUP_PERSON_COMPANY_LINK i:nil="true"/>
               <a:Company_Id>6</a:Company_Id>
               <a:Customer_Id>1</a:Customer_Id>
               <a:Email_Address/>
               <a:First_Name>abc</a:First_Name>
               <a:Invoice_Contact_Enum>true</a:Invoice_Contact_Enum>
               <a:Job_Title_Enum>Trader</a:Job_Title_Enum>
               <a:Last_Modify_Date>2017-04-06T10:55:41.05</a:Last_Modify_Date>
               <a:Last_Name>xyz</a:Last_Name>
               <a:Lock_Id>3</a:Lock_Id>
               <a:Middle_Name/>
               <a:Modify_Person_Id>1</a:Modify_Person_Id>
               <a:Person_Id>2</a:Person_Id>
               <a:Person_Initials>PB</a:Person_Initials>
               <a:Status_Enum>false</a:Status_Enum>
               <a:System_Default_Enum i:nil="true"/>
            </a:DTOCtrmSetupPerson>
```

i have posted a part out of that xml, there are more than 10 person.
what i want is to get the person depending on the `<a:Job_Title_Enum>` and assign the respective person ID to that person. for eg: if the Job_Title_Enum is "trader" then the first name and last name will be added into a list with each person having its respective personID

i have implemented a method for parsing which i found online
method:-

```
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("E:\\GetAllPersonresponse.xml");
            textReader.Read();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(textReader);

            XmlNodeList FirstName = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("a:First_Name");
            XmlNodeList LastName = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("a:Last_Name");
            XmlNodeList JobTitle = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("a:Job_Title_Enum");
            XmlNodeList personID = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("a:Person_Id");

            for (int i = 0; i < JobTitle.Count; i++)
            {


               if (JobTitle[i].InnerText == "Trader")
               {

                    Trader.Add(FirstName[i].InnerText + " " + LastName[i].InnerText +"(" + personID[i].InnerText+")");

               }


            }
```

this method makes a list of "Firstname Lastname (PersonID)" eg:- Admin Admin (1). could you please suggest me an efficient method? which will assign the ID rather than printing it on the list because i would be adapting this list to spinner.

Comment: I recommend using XLinq if you don't have a performance requirement. Makes querying XML a breeze.

Comment: Could you please post a sample for my XML?

Comment: Actually this looks like a SOAP service. Can you add a web reference in VS? It will auto-generate C# classes for you.

Comment: I had to go with this method because for some odd reason i was not able to create the object of my service  after adding it as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Linq2Xml,

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
//var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

XNamespace a = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DTOModelLayer.DTO";

var persons = xDoc.Descendants(a + "DTOCtrmSetupPerson")
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        firstName = (string)x.Element(a + "First_Name"),
                        personId = (int)x.Element(a + "Person_Id")
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. This works! as this is a list, i want to adapt this list to my spinner, when i select an item from this list i will select it in this way- string selecteditem = spinner.getselecteditem.tostring(); now, how will i get the selected person's ID here?

Comment: How can i extract personId of the selected list element for eg:- string selecteditem = spinner.getselecteditem.getpersonID.tostring();

Comment: Yes you're right! I am just asking how to extract the personID from the persons list. That's it.